# Phpstorm Xdebug Magento Ajax call not stopping on breakpoint on Innoexts/Warehouse/Checkout/OnepageController/saveOrder

Tags: magento, xdebug

My phpstorm (version 8.0.2) with Xdebug, working on ecommerce site built in Magento 1.6.2, the xdebug breakpoint works normally, but when I debug with an Ajax call, which is from this community module - Innoexts/Warehouse/Checkout/OnepageController.php saveOrderAction, the breakpoint doesn't stop.

Answer (score 0):

Is your module installed via Composer? I've noticed in the past that PHPStorm 8 + Xdebug doesn't play well with the symlinked third-party files, and you may need to set the breakpoint on the file in the vendor/ directory instead.

Otherwise, this suggests that another module is overriding that route with their own action. Check for OnepageController files in other modules, and check if they've also replaced the saveOrderAction.